# What is the default number of threads running in the JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I've been learning more about thread and I was wondering why the resource monitor shows always 19 threads running for the Java process.

Now my questions are:

- Is this the VM using 19 threads?

If so:

- Are you able to access those threads?
- Is it possible to use these threads for thread pooling?
- Is it possible to decrease the amount of threads?

If not:

- What is causing to show up the 19 threads?

I created a small .jar (see bottom for source) that would run and create a fixed threadpool of 5 worker threads. To that pool I sent tasks and I noticed that after all tasks have been handled, the amount of threads java uses goes back to 19.

Are the threads in the fixed threadpool idle or have they been removed and thus new threads are being created whenever new tasks are submitted?

Sorry for the multiple questions in one post.

- Link to source: http://pastebin.com/iXpLbFVF
- Image while sending tasks: http://gyazo.com/223d720bf73c1b919fbfe0b69088838a
- Image after sending tasks: http://gyazo.com/3147269d90eb2c916373220ef53c0b92

Comment: The JVM has many threads. It has the GC which is always running. If you are running from an IDE then there are probably multiple JMX threads. Use JConsole or JVisualVM to see what the threads are doing/are called - this will explain things. Your `FixedThreadPool` will keep the threads alive until you shut it down.

Comment: Those image links won't work for me (now).  And the paste-bin links are likely to stop working too.  Questions should not depend on "evidence" hosted in an external service that is likely to be transitory.

Comment: There is no 'default number'. It depends on what parts of the JRE you're using. There are GC threads, there's an event thread if you're using AWT or Swing, there are RMI threads for various purposes if you're using RMI, ...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the JVM version, the JVM vendor and some settings like which garbage collector is in place (and how the GC is tuned). Also some add-ons like agents or JMX can change the system running threads. And of course all threads started by the actual Java program. You can use the [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html) program to actually list them (most of the system threads have obvious names). They include threads for finalisation, GC, the main thread, the Gui threads (if used), also JIT Compiler Threads and reference weakeners.

Comment: +1 - Key point: use `jstack` to help you figure out what the threads are.